Proving that mgf determines distribution via Laplace transform
I am reading this question and the answer provided there about the moment generating function (mgf) and how its uniqueness can be proved via the uniqueness of Laplace transforms. In my book, Measure theory, Probability and Stochastic processes by Le Gall, the uniqueness of the Laplace transform of a nonnegative random variable is proved, but I really struggle understanding how this result can be extended for a random variable of arbitrary sign, to say that the mgf, which really is a two-sided Laplace transform, determines the law of $X$.
I think the answer in the linked post makes a false statement. The answer claims that

$$M_X(-t)=\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}(t)+\mathcal{L}\{f(-x)\}(-t),$$and $M_X(t)$ is unique iff both $\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}(t)$ and $\mathcal{L}\{f(-x)\}(-t)$ are unique.

But addition is not injective. Suppose $Y$ is given with density $g(x)$. If $M_X(-t)=M_Y(-t)$ for some $|t|<h$ where $h>0$, and if $F(t)=\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}(t)$, $G(t)=\mathcal{L}\{f(-x)\}(-t)$, $H(t)=\mathcal{L}\{g(x)\}(t)$ and $K(t)=\mathcal{L}\{g(-x)\}(-t)$, then $$F(t)+G(t)=H(t)+K(t)\rlap{\ \quad\not\ }\implies F(t)=H(t),G(t)=K(t),$$so it seems like we can't use the uniqueness of the Laplace transform to conclude that $f(x)=g(x)$ and $f(-x)=g(-x)$ on $x>0$, so that $f(x)=g(x)$.
Is my reasoning correct or am I misunderstanding something? E.g. Casella and Berger also refer to this result as a result from Laplace transform theory, but I do not see how the quoted statement above is true or how to prove the mgf determines the law of $X$ given we know that the one-sided Laplace transform determines the law of $X$.

You are right that the used logic is not correct. A clear counterexample, where the same logic leads to a false conclusion is
$$M_{f(x)}'(-t)=\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}(t)+\mathcal{L}\{f(-x)\}(t)$$
Here $\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}(t)$ and $\mathcal{L}\{f(-x)\}(t)$ are both one sided Laplace transforms with the uniqueness property, but that doesn't mean that a sum like that is unique as well. In particular the functions $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$, which don't need to be the same, lead to the same transforms.

Alternative proofs: Proof that moment generating functions uniquely determine probability distributions
